# PHP connection to SQL Server 2012

Tags: php, sql-server-2012

Till now, I was used to connect to local MySQL databases with:

```
$db=new mysqli('localhost', 'root','','apeirosto');       
if ($db->connect_errno) 
  ...
```

Now, it is the case I want to connect to an existing SQL Server 2012 database (**named seminars**) over the network. If the IP of the host of the db is **10.1.8.13**, what do I have to write as to establish the connection? I tried the following:

```
$db=mssql_connect('10.1.8.13\sqlmix', 'root','','seminars');
```

Unfortunately, it did not work(sqlmix is necessary). Sorry,but this is the first time I am dealing with SQL Server. Have in mind that PHP communicates with SQL Server; this is sure. The problem is the wrong command syntax.

Thank you

Comment: Did you check 10.1.8.13\sqlmix has public database access?

Comment: Yes, my static IP has

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mssql_connect('10.1.8.13\sqlmix', 'root','');
```

Comment: You may need to use this function too http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-select-db.php

Comment: @ILIAS First you connect with the proper syntax and select db.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$server="SD-20120627VVKE\\SQLEXPRESS";

$options = array("UID" => "<username>","PWD" =>"<password>","Database"=>"android_api");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $options);

if ($conn === false) die("<pre>".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
echo "Successfully connected!";
sqlsrv_close($conn);
```